# joomla 2.5 categories are crashing

Tags: joomla, crash, categories

After my hosting company upgraded the server I have a really strange issue with the categories. Every second day a category crashes and when clicking the linked menu item it shows the following error. Can you help please? Thank you. ( http://myxolargos.gr)

> error: 500
>
> Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_1325_1.MYI'; try to repair it
>   SQL=SELECT a.id, a.title, a.alias, a.title_alias, a.introtext,
>   a.checked_out, a.checked_out_time, a.catid, a.created, a.created_by,
>   a.created_by_alias, CASE WHEN a.modified = 0 THEN a.created ELSE
>   a.modified END as modified, a.modified_by, uam.name as
>   modified_by_name,CASE WHEN a.publish_up = 0 THEN a.created ELSE
>   a.publish_up END as publish_up,a.publish_down, a.images, a.urls,
>   a.attribs, a.metadata, a.metakey, a.metadesc, a.access, a.hits,
>   a.xreference, a.featured, LENGTH(a.fulltext) AS readmore,CASE WHEN
>   badcats.id is not null THEN 0 ELSE a.state END AS state,c.title AS
>   category_title, c.path AS category_route, c.access AS category_access,
>   c.alias AS category_alias,CASE WHEN a.created_by_alias > ' ' THEN
>   a.created_by_alias ELSE ua.name END AS author,ua.email AS
>   author_email,( SELECT MAX(contact.id) AS id FROM
>   myxolarg_contact_details AS contact WHERE contact.published = 1 AND
>   contact.user_id = a.created_by) as contactid,parent.title as
>   parent_title, parent.id as parent_id, parent.path as parent_route,
>   parent.alias as parent_alias,ROUND(v.rating_sum / v.rating_count, 0)
>   AS rating, v.rating_count as rating_count,c.published, CASE WHEN
>   badcats.id is null THEN c.published ELSE 0 END AS parents_published
>   FROM myxolarg_content AS a LEFT JOIN myxolarg_content_frontpage AS fp
>   ON fp.content_id = a.id LEFT JOIN myxolarg_categories AS c ON c.id =
>   a.catid LEFT JOIN myxolarg_users AS ua ON ua.id = a.created_by LEFT
>   JOIN myxolarg_users AS uam ON uam.id = a.modified_by LEFT JOIN
>   myxolarg_categories as parent ON parent.id = c.parent_id LEFT JOIN
>   myxolarg_content_rating AS v ON a.id = v.content_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
>   (SELECT cat.id as id FROM myxolarg_categories AS cat JOIN
>   myxolarg_categories AS parent ON cat.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND
>   parent.rgt WHERE parent.extension = 'com_content' AND parent.published
>   != 1 GROUP BY cat.id ) AS badcats ON badcats.id = c.id WHERE a.access
>   IN (1,1) AND c.access IN (1,1) AND CASE WHEN badcats.id is null THEN
>   a.state ELSE 0 END = 1 AND (a.catid = 109 OR a.catid IN ( SELECT
>   sub.id FROM myxolarg_categories as sub INNER JOIN myxolarg_categories
>   as this ON sub.lft > this.lft AND sub.rgt < this.rgt WHERE this.id =
>   109)) AND (a.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR a.publish_up <=
>   '2014-02-12 21:58:27') AND (a.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR
>   a.publish_down >= '2014-02-12 21:58:27') ORDER BY c.lft, CASE WHEN
>   a.publish_up = 0 THEN a.created ELSE a.publish_up END DESC , a.created
>   LIMIT 0, 11

Comment: Login to PhpMyAdmin, select the `#__categories` table and click the "repair" option

Comment: Already tried it, didn't work unfortunatelly!

Comment: What version of mysql are you now using?

Answer (score 0):

Check your hosting account has not run out of space.

[How do you fix a MySQL "Incorrect key file" error when you can't repair the table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428738/how-do-you-fix-a-mysql-incorrect-key-file-error-when-you-cant-repair-the-tabl) indicates that their solution was to ensure the tmp folder had enough space remaining to perform the repai.

If your hosting company has just changed something, then perhaps they have done something that would affect your tmp folder location for MYSQL.

Comment: They have upagraded PHP they told me. It's a nightmare, I have 5 news portals and every second a category crashes and I have to create a new one and transfer as much articles as I can until it crashes again! The modules stop displaying the categories and the whole site crashes.