# AWS Aurora ALTER TABLE not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to add a new column to a table that weighs about 20GB using:

```
ALTER TBLE ... ALGORYTHM = INPLACE
```

After about one hour of processing, the ALTER command fails and returns the following error without adding the column:

```
ERROR 1034 (HY000): Incorrect key file for table '[TABLE]'; try to repair it
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428738/how-do-you-fix-a-mysql-incorrect-key-file-error-when-you-cant-repair-the-tabl

Comment: @mickzer This thread is not really relevant because AWS does not provide access to the file system. In addition, the table engine is InnoDB so the repair option is not available. Also, Aurora is not really MySQL, It's "MySQL compatible" so I'm not really sure that even if we had access to the file system, it would be the same as MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue related to temporary disk space.

It's a known problem in Aurora: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=691512

Comment: that link is no longer working